# Parameterizing a parameterized method's return type

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion, parameterized

I have been trying to get something like this working:

```
private static <V, K> V<KnownType> from(K oldObject, Class<? extends V<KnownType>> newClass) {
    ...
}
```

However, this method signature gets a compiler error:

> The type V is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<KnownType>`

Basically, I want a method that converts `K` to `V<KnownType>`.  Is this possible?

Also, some additional context in case somebody writes code for this -- all `V`'s have a single-argument constructor that take in a `K`.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** -- The input class is a subclass of V. (`? extends V...`)

Comment: Can you change the inheritance hierarchy of the classes in question?

Comment: I am building a layer on top of an SDK, which itself cannot be modified.  So I can't modify `K` or `KnownType`, but I can modify `V` and all its subclasses.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Reflection is fragile.

Comment: Because I hate duplicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
public interface SomeType<E>
```

Try this:

```
private static <V extends SomeType<KnownType>, K> V from(K oldObject, Class<V> newClass) {
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind when I asked if you can change the inheritance hierarchy. From your response, it sounds like you can do it: introduce `SomeType` in the ancestry of the classes you want to be able to use for `V`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid changing those classes, but this seems to be the only solution.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Type parameters in Java can only correspond to a *type*. You want `V` to be something that itself takes a type, a higher "kind" of thing that operates on types. Generics in Java don't work with higher kinds.